# Why my all page data is showing StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Error showing stack overflow

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/arima/chromedriver/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://education-india.in/Education/Courses/?PageNumber=1");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    List<WebElement> dropdown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='txtPageNumber']/option"));

    for(int k=1;k<dropdown.size()-1;k++) {
        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr"));
        List<WebElement> col = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr[1]/th"));

        for(int i=0;i<rows.size()-1;i++){
            System.out.println(rows.get(i).getText());
        }

        dropdown.get(k).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        /*
         * WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
         * wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(dropdown));
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException this one is my error

Comment: which one you want to select ?

Comment: i want to go one by one page and print current page web table

Comment: plzhelp guys..this one showing staleelementexception

Comment: @shona : Try my answer?

Comment: except thread.sleep how i put webdriverwait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

ERROR comes when webdriver failed to identify the element on that page.You need to re-assign your dropdown element inside for loop.try the below code.

```
driver.get("http://education-india.in/Education/Courses/?PageNumber=1");
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        List<WebElement> dropdown =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//select[@id='txtPageNumber']/option")));


        for(int k=1;k<dropdown.size()-1;k++) {
            List<WebElement> newdropdown =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//select[@id='txtPageNumber']/option")));

            List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr"));
            List<WebElement> col = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr[1]/th"));

            for(int i=0;i<rows.size()-1;i++){
                System.out.println(rows.get(i).getText());
            }

            newdropdown.get(k).click();

        }
```

Comment: That's NOT what causes a `StaleElementReferenceException`. A stale element is one that you have a reference to (stored in a variable) and the page refreshes changes in such a way that the exact element you stored is no longer on the page. What you are talking about is more like a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: @JeffC : When you check other people code selenium throws the  `StaleElementReferenceException`  please try the op code and check what error are you getting.I am getting the `StaleElementReferenceException` exception when  I ran OP code.OP also confirmed that if you see OP comment in comment box.

Comment: I'm talking about your explanation of `StaleElementReferenceException`. You stated `ERROR comes when webdriver failed to identify the element on that page.` which is not correct.

Comment: @JeffC : Sorry for that i might write the explanation wrong way.However the solution is correct. However I'll keep in mind but i think i don't deserve down vote for the same. for the sake of writing.

Comment: how to store this one in excel sheet

Comment: @shone you have to post a new question with your new requirements along with code.

Comment: plz kunduK u help me .same code in the above.but i want to show in excel sheet

Comment: @shona : For excel you have to use Apache POI.Check following link which is very good tutorial to learn. https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/keyword-driven-framework/set-excel-apache-poi/

Comment: i cant understand .u plz try once

Answer (score 0):

Since the dropdown is a select element. you could use a select object to select the page.

The reason for stale element reference error is every time the page loads, the dropdown's locator stays the same but it is not the same element. The dropdown also gets refreshed. That is why you have to locate the dropdown after every page load.

Try this:

```java
    driver.get("http://education-india.in/Education/Courses/?PageNumber=1");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("txtPageNumber")));

    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='txtPageNumber']/option"));

    for (int k = 0; k<options.size(); k++) {
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='txtPageNumber']"))).selectByIndex(k);

        List<WebElement> rows = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr")));
        List<WebElement> col = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr[1]/th"));

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size()-1; i++) {
            System.out.println("PRE: "+rows.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
```

Comment: this one is help full .but i want to store this data in excel sheet ..plz help  how to do it